# Какой корень в слове НАШЕЛ?

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Какой корень в слове НАШЕЛ? Есть ли ссылка на достоверный современный источник?
Причем интересует в значении обнаружить что-то. Не согласна с приставкой НА, думаю, корень НАШ-е(суф.)-л(суф.). Верно ли это?

Answer (score 2):

Согласна с Вами, приставка не выделяется. Современный источник - грамматико-орфографический словарь Панова и Текучёва и Словарь строения слов Потихи. Там дан разбор начальной формы: най/ти. Но есть второе значение "нашёл на камень" от "идти", вот там   на/шё/л.

Если Нашёл от "найти, искать", то нашё/л - наш/л/а - наход/к/а

нулевое окончание,

нашё - корень,ё-беглый гласный, не суфф.

нашё - основа слова,

л - суффикс прошедшего времени (в основу не входит).

Пользоваться словарём -онлайн не советую, там разбирает "машина" и ошибок много.

Comment: Людмила, я проголосовал за Ваш ответ: корень _**нашё**_ выделяет в слове _**нашёл**_ и Тихонов ("Словарь-справочник по русскому языку", М., 1997). Согласен с Вашим замечанием и по поводу онлайн-словарей. Но, к сожалению, разнобой возможен не только в них. Есть и в бумажных. К примеру,  у Баранова М.Т. в _"Школьном орфографическом словаре русского языка" (М., 2015)_  приведено такое морфемное членение причастия _найденный_ : **на/йд/енн/ый**. Приставка "на-"?

Comment: К сожалению, это есть, но вряд ли это формально-структурный метод, как говорит Вера. В этом словаре я видела и просто орфографические ошибки. Видимо, к его корректуре отнеслись тоже формально.Когда у нас выступали разработчики КИМов, мы задали вопрос о разнобое в словарях. Профессор ответил: "Потому мы и убрали из ЕГЭ вопросы по словообразованию и морфемному составу", там неразбериха и откровенные ошибки в учебных изданиях

Answer (score 0):

Не имеет смысла проводить сравнительный анализ словарей и искать достоверные источники, но надо понять суть **двух принципиально различных методов морфемного разбора**.

Источник: http://www.gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part2.htm

**Следует различать формально-структурный и формально-смысловой методы анализа**

**1) На/шё/л (что-то)**

Суть **формально-структурного морфемного разбора** состоит в том, что в основе в первую очередь выделяется корень как общая часть родственных слов. Затем то, что идет до корня, учеником должно быть осознано как приставка (приставки) в соответствии с представлениями ученика о том, встречались ли ему подобные элементы в других словах. Аналогично с суффиксами.

Ошибки в определении корня слова связаны **с неразличением синхронного морфемного и исторического (этимологического) состава слова.** Так, в учебнике по теории в качестве иллюстративного материала приведен такой пример морфемного разбора слова искусство (ис-кус-ств-о). Очевидно, что такой подход не может способствовать корректному выделению корня в современной структуре слова и приводит к выделению в основе незначимых сегментов.

Формально-структурный подход к морфемному членению слова не является исключительно принадлежностью школьной практики. Аналогичный подход осуществлен в ряде научных изданий, например в «Словаре морфем русского языка» А. И. Кузнецовой и Т. Ф. Ефремовой, где утверждается, что «морфемный анализ мало зависит от словообразовательного, так как обычно при членении слова используется сопоставительный метод, при котором практически не учитывается, что от чего образуется».

**2) Нашё/л** (что-то)

Формально-структурному подходу противопоставлен подход **формально-смысловой (формально-семантический).** Главная установка данного подхода и алгоритм морфемного разбора выходят из трудов Г. О. Винокура и состоят **в неразрывности морфемного членения и словообразовательного разбора.** О том, что этот подход является целесообразным и даже единственно возможным, писали многие ученые и методисты на протяжении многих десятилетий.

Алгоритм морфемного разбора основы состоит **в построении словообразовательной цепочки «наоборот»**: со слова как бы «снимаются» приставки и суффиксы, корень же выделяется в последнюю очередь. При разборе постоянно необходимо соотнесение значения производного и значения его производящего; производящая основа в современном русском языке — основа мотивирующая. Если между значением производного и значением производящего (в нашем представлении) слова нет отношения мотивированности, производящее выбрано неверно.
Примеры: плотнич/а/л

Comment: Vera,  Литневская всё написала правильно относительно слов _искусство, плотничал_… Но про слово _**на/шё/л (что-то)**_ она, по-моему,  ничего не писала. **Это Ваш пример**, Вам и _отдуваться_… У Литневской так: _"Суть формально-структурного морфемного разбора состоит в том, что в основе в первую очередь **выделяется корень как общая часть родственных слов"**._  Какие родственные к _**нашёл**_ (в знач. _отыскать_ что- или кого-л.) слова можно было бы привести, чтобы выделить в этом слове корень "шё"?

Comment: Во многих случаях формально-структурный и формально-смысловой разборы совпадают, но вот слово "нашёл" к этим вариантам не относится. С одной стороны,  мы  ясно осознаем, что найти - это как бы "набрести" на предмет и обнаружить его, нет сомнения, что НА - это приставка с соответствующим значением, и значение корня  тоже понятно. Новый смысл у слова "нашёл" является переносным,  и  это понимается носителями языка, но это уже новое слово. Вот здесь и  становятся уместными два варианта разбора.

Comment: А вот для слова "искусство" не стоит пользоваться формальным способом, так как мы уже не понимаем значение корня  КУС без этимологического словаря. Вот здесь и должна проходить еще одна граница того сегмента слов, где возможен двойной разбор. Всё чётко, всё по определению, но вряд ли этот вариант найдет применение в ближайшее время.

Comment: Потому что норма современной филологии  - это расплывчатые понятия и бесконечные споры о предметах, не имеющих ТОЧНОГО ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ.  Так что здесь еще не раз будут задаваться подобные вопросы, и на них будут даваться те же самые ответы, что и сейчас (один к одному).

Comment: Вера, и все же: вряд ли на современном этапе языка в этом слове можно выделить корень шё. Чтобы что-то найти необязательно идти куда-то и на что-то набрести.

Comment: Серж, вы сомневаетесь, что найти (что-то)  - это переносное (образное) значение глагола найти со значением движения? Вы не узнаете приставу НА и корень ШЁ/Л? Конечно же, вы их узнаете, это и есть формальный метод разбора. Но вы можете пользоваться семантическим методом : НАШЁ/Л, если он Вам больше нравится. Только нужно не забывать, что он именно семантический и не единственный в современном понимании ситуации (существуют два метода, две разные школы).

Answer (score 0):

Понятно что "нашёл" образовался от "идти". Чтобы искать что-то (например грибы) надо ходить. Ты шёл, шёл и **на**шёл. Это результат действия - ходьбы с целью поиска. Потом это значение стало более образным и расширилось вообще на любую находку, любым образом найденную. Поэтому корень - "шё", от "идти".

По-моему то, что это слово образовалось от "идти", так же очевидно как и для слова "пришел". Так зачем выделять какой-то новый корень "наше", только школьников запутывать.

Comment: С одной стороны так, с другой не так. Исторический корень поменял своё значение и в современности это уже не однокоренные слова. Если учитывать историч. корень как действующий, получится об/лак/о,за/с/тен/чив/ый (в тени),до/клад, за/вет, об/ман, за/каз/чик. Кому-то это понятно, кого-то ещё больше запутает. Я думаю, нужно разбирать в соответствии с современным состоянием языка

Comment: @Людмила Только если подходить, как вы говорите, то возникает одна проблема. Не в слове "нашёл", а в вообще она возможна. А именно: от того приставка это или часть корня, может зависеть написание. Например, твердый знак пишется только после приставок, в другой позиции он невозможен. Или приставки заканчивающиеся на звонкий перед корнем, который начинается на глухой. Поэтому, как мне кажется, этимологический подход лучше.